# problems with php mcrypt mac 10.8 install

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

I'm having some issues with getting mcrypt setup on my local php server.  I initially tried to use homebrew, but when calling a mcrypt function, it said that it errored saying that the function was unavailable.

I tried troubleshooting a bit, but I think I accidently added mcrypt to a place other than the homebrew installed php, and now I can't seem to uninstall it, and now I can't seem to install mcrypt through homebrew anymore.  I get the following error:

```
{php-5.3.27 tim$ brew install mcrypt
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mcrypt/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8 --mandir=/usr/local/Cell
==> make install
Warning: Could not link mcrypt. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link mcrypt'

Possible conflicting files are:
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8: 12 files, 348K, built in 26 seconds}
```

any help would be great

thanks

Answer (score -1):

The following command of ./configure is make.

and, next is make install.

1. ./configure
2. make
3. make install